# Smooth scroll-snap-type in MobileSafari?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

This seems simple enough however I am having issues with scroll-snap-type and scroll-snap-align on iOS Safari, where in order for the scroll-snap to actually work, you have to do a "full" swipe, or swipe at least a large majority of the screen, as opposed to any scroll or swipe at all. Doing a "small" swipe jumps the screen back to the top of the section currently in the viewport. Scrolling up is a mess in itself, where the scroll will seem to stop mid-way through at the beginning of the end of the content in the above section.

This results in general bugginess and choppy scrolling and other inconsistencies, and I was wondering if I was doing something wrong or if somebody was able to provide a solution I was missing.

Relevant code:

```
.scroll-container {
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }
    
section {
      height: 100vh;
      scroll-snap-align: start;
      background-color: black;
      padding-top: 10%;
    }
```

I've tried basically everything I can think of; various scroll-snap-stop options, proximity, etc; almost every variation of options possible, removing padding; none of it just seems to get a smooth scroll to the next section.

I'm pretty lost at this point; of course, the desktop experience is smooth and works exactly as expected. If there is a javascript or jquery alternative, that works for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and tried everything under the sun, but scroll snapping was still choppy in safari iOS.

What you're experiencing is likely because of how Safari calculates viewport and the fact that it has a menu bar which dissappears when you swipe and causes the viewport to change again.

[image: viewport calculation on safari iOS]

You can read more about that [here](https://medium.com/rbi-tech/safaris-100vh-problem-3412e6f13716).

Personally, I worked around this by using a framework called [Swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/get-started), because any other solution I tried was still choppy.